# Generic class, constraint by struct, generate compile time error "Use of unassigned local variable"

Tags: c#, generics

I have next code:

```
class GenericStruct<T> where T : struct
{
    public void M()
    {
        T temp1;
        T temp2;
        string s = temp1.ToString();
        Type t = temp1.GetType();
        bool b = temp1.Equals(temp2);
    }
}
```

i got two errors "Use of unassigned local variable" when call methods: ToString and Equals, but GetType is ok.
The ting, that "disturb" me is fact, of presence of

```
where T : struct
```

But, if i wrote:

```
struct NotGenericStruct
{
    public void M()
    {
        NotGenericStruct temp1;
        NotGenericStruct temp2;
        string s = temp1.ToString();
        Type t = temp1.GetType();
        bool b = temp1.Equals(temp2);
    }
}
```

is ok, no errors at compile time.
I understand, that struct data type have default constructor and all members are initialized, so no need write explicit new.

what exactly the difference between two peaces of code? Please, explain me my incomprehension

Thanks

Comment: Use default(T) to initialize your variables

Comment: @Groo I'm not sure id it is a duplicate. The question, if I understood correctly, is "_what is the difference_" rather than "_how to fix_".

Comment: I would agree this shouldn't really be closed. The question is about why the compiler allows use of unassigned local variable in the second example when it is an explicit struct but not in the first example when it is an implicit struct.

Comment: The answer seems to be that if the struct has no fields then it doesn't need to be initialised.

Comment: @Chris: yes, you are correct, you should post the answer, I reopened the question. The reason that the latter example doesn't fail is that `NotGenericStruct` has no fields, which cannot be guaranteed for the generic `T : struct`.

Comment: @Groo: Done. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement

```
class GenericStruct<T> where T : struct
```

[`struct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) indicates that `T` is a by-value type.

> The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except `Nullable` can be specified.

So `T` could be, for example, `int`. And in such a case the statement

```
T temp1;
```

leaves `temp1` uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the difference in behaviour between these two pieces of code is that in the generic case all we know is that T is a struct. We cannot make any more assumptions beyond that. We don't know if the struct has methods, fields, properties, constructors or anything else.

In the second case we know that the struct is of type `NotGenericStruct` and we know everything there is to know about this struct. In particular we can see that all it has on it is a single method. This means that we know that there is actually no state that needs to be initialised on this object.

I can't quote the exact part of the langauge spec that allows this but it is clear to see that the compiler allows an unitialised struct because it knows it would be absolutely identical to if you had done `new NotGenericStruct`.

It is easy to see the difference in behaviour because if you add an int field (or any other type) to `NotGenericStruct` then it will immediately start complaining about use of an uninitialised local variable (refering to `NotGenericStruct` now it has fields).

In general though this is a very special case which only applies for structs with no fields. Any classes or any structs with fields *needs* to be initialised so generally it is best and easiest to assume that *all* locals need initialisation. It is certainly likely to produce more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class GenericStruct<T> where T : struct
{
    public void M()
    {
        T temp1 = default(T);
        T temp2 = default(T);
        string s = temp1.ToString();
        Type t = temp1.GetType();
        bool b = temp1.Equals(temp2);
    }
}
```